# Updating env file from command line in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I want to update database password inside the env file. I want to update the `db_password` variable.

I am trying the following command after navigation to `/var/www/html`

`php artisan env:set db_password=myPassWordHere`

And I am getting error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
```

Full error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(202): Monolog\Logger->error(Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(113): Illuminate\Log\Writer->writeLog('error', Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundati in /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
```

How can I update db_password variable inside env file, using command line?

Comment: "_Permission denied_" says it all in the error message. Make sure your CLI/webserver can write to `storage/logs/laravel.log`. After you can write to that file, read it and you'll see the error

Answer (score 1):

Check that the log file exists and that it has write permissions:

```
ls -l /var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

If it's not writable, run:

```
chmod 755 /var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

Comment: I am getting this after ls command `-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 23137182 Feb  2 18:58 /var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: After running chmod command, I am getting `chmod: changing permissions of '/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log': Operation not permitted
`

Comment: @Ilham try this `sudo chmod 755 /var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log` as a root user

Comment: Tried just like you said with root user, and now permissions look like this `-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 23395137 Feb  2 19:18 /var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log
`, but after running the `php artisan env:set db_password=myPassWordHere` command I still get that same `Permission denied` error.

Comment: Use 766 rather than 755. `sudo chmod 766 /var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Github Package https://github.com/svenluijten/flex-env

After the Successful Package Installation

For Example
If you want to add new constant to **.env** File

Maybe if you want to add `ADMIN_EMAIL` with the value `admin@app.com`

```sh
php artisan env:set ADMIN_EMAIL admin@app.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to resolve it by running the following set of commands.

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

(In that order)